# Could not load System.Drawing V4.0.0.0 on a VB.Net Windows form in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I've decided to learn Visual Basic .Net as this is what some of my colleagues work with, and this will allow me to work with them on projects.

I have purchased Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Step by Step and downloaded the sample files. When I am trying to debug the first sample application (a Windows form), it is telling me that it can't load System.Drawing V4.0.0.0. However, if I create a new Windows Form application (C# or VB.Net) this works fine.

I had a look at the References tab in the project settings and System.Windows.Forms is referenced, but the version referenced is 2.0.0.0. I have removed and re-added this reference and it stays at 2.0.0.0 and I still get the error.

Does anybody have any ideas as to what may be going on?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Thanks

Comment: This can happen when you add a resource and *later* change the framework target.  The resource is still locked into the default target selection, 4.0.0.0 for VS2010.  Beyond removing the resource and adding it back, a simple workaround is to just leave it targeting .NET version 4.  If you copied your project from somewhere then that's relevant as well but you didn't mention that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify. The solution is a sample solution written by the books author and I get this error when trying to debug it (as per the authors instructions). When I make a new Windows Form, everything works fine. Also, the book is for Visual Basic 2010, the solution is a VS 2010 *.sln file and I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Then it is very unclear how you ended up with a reference to Winforms 2.0.0.0, focus on that.

Comment: @Hans - I agree, it sounds like there is more to the story than this.  Exact errors and some code would help, as would details on the reference properties.

Comment: This may sound silly, but you note that System.Windows.Forms is referenced but that the problem is with System.Drawing... is the System.Drawing reference in your list?

Comment: Better yet, here's a link - http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735626690.do, if you click on 'Download Example Files' on the bottom right hand side of the screen you can see this for yourself

Comment: MusicTrivia?  It works fine for me.  Do any of your references have a yellow exclamation point? Are any of them (in Properties) "Resolved : False"?  Could you copy the EXACT error you recieve and put it in your post?

Comment: "An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." - A screenshot is here - http://i42.tinypic.com/347k8so.jpg, how does this compare to what you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a discrepancy in the target framework.  v4.0.0.0 is targeting .NET framework v4.0 - v2.0.0.0 is targeting .NET framework v2.0.  You can change the framework target for your project in

```
Project -> 
   (myProject) Properties... -> 
      Compile -> 
         Advanced Compile Options -> 
            Target Framework...
```

Comment: Tried this! I get the error regardless of what Framework I target. The book and sample files are for Visual Basic 2010, and I am using Visual Studio 2010 so I shouldn't really have to change any of this stuff anyways

Comment: If you're adding 2.0 references it is because your project is targeting .NET v2.0.  The IDE, afaik, won't offer you 4.0 libraries unless your project is targeting .NET 4.0.  Are you saying that the references in the sample projects are for 2.0 libraries?  Do you have .NET 2.0 installed?

Comment: hmm I never explicitly installed .Net 2.0. I assumed that as I am running VS2010 SP1 on Windows 7 SP1, .Net 2.0 would be on my computer. Is this not the case?

Comment: It should be.  Perhaps the examples have x86 only dependencies?  Did you try switching your target CPU to x86 (from AnyCPU or x64)?

Comment: I've tried this, also tried repairing Visual Studio, same issue!

Answer (score 1):

Dont target .Net 4.0 CLIENT, target the .Net 4.0 FULL framework